# Ido mode - autocomplete in interactively mode

Tags: completion, minibuffer, auto-complete-mode

#### windows 10, emacs 26,1, ido mode

I use `ido` mode.

Suppose I start some command

```
M-x magit
```

Then <kbd>TAB</kbd>

The possible completions are many and fill the screen:

[image]

I need to continue typing and press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to select desire command. 
But... it's very slow.

Is  it a more interactive way? like fly filter commands' name in `ido` mode. Something similar to `helm` only I don't like `helm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend `Smex`:

```
(use-package smex
  :bind (("M-x" . smex))
  :config (smex-initialize))
```

[Getting started guide](https://github.com/nonsequitur/smex/) on Github:

> Smex is a M-x enhancement for Emacs. Built on top of Ido, it provides a convenient interface to your recently and most frequently used commands. And to all the other commands, too.

Find it on [emacs wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Smex)

Including example code and links.

Comment: OK. Package "smex" work fine with files, buffers. But what about list of shell history commands (dir, copy, mkdir and so on). I also need this in shell mode.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking for *incremental completion*: the completion candidates are shown and updated as you type into the minibuffer.

1. You get that using [Icomplete](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IcompleteMode) mode. It originally just showed you the candidates, without giving you a way to choose one, but starting a few Emacs releases ago it also lets you pick a candidate. It shows only some of the candidates, and it shows them in the minibuffer. Icomplete is part of vanilla Emacs, and library [`icomplete+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/icomplete%2b.el) offers some enhancements.
2. [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) gives you [more flexible](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Icompletion#IncrementalCompletion) incremental completion, and you can easily customize the behavior (change the delay or the number of chars before starting to show candidates, show candidates from the outset, toggle it on/off on the fly, etc.). Candidates are shown in buffer `*Completions*`.

   The default behavior of Icicles is different from Ido, but you can change the behavior to be [more like Ido](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Ido_and_IswitchB), if you like.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the IDO [documentation](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings#toc10), you can place the following inside your Emacs init file.

```lisp
(global-set-key
 "\M-x"
 (lambda ()
   (interactive)
   (call-interactively
    (intern
     (ido-completing-read "M-x " (all-completions "" obarray 'commandp))))
   )
 )
```

Make sure you have already setup `ido-mode` correctly, before settings the above global binding.